# sprintf pad string on right with dash

Tags: perl, printf

I need to pad a string on the right with dashes ('-'). e.g. convert `'M'` to `'M-----'`.

`sprintf "%-6s", "M";` gives me `'M     '`. I tried `printf "%-6-s", "M";`, and `printf "%--6s", "M";`, but neither of those work...

Can this be done with `sprinf` and if so, how?

Comment: `sprintf("%-6s", "M") =~ tr| |-|r;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be done with `sprintf` alone. (`sprintf` will only pad with spaces or with zeroes.)

```
sprintf("%-6s", $s) =~ tr/ /-/r
```

or

```
substr($s.("-" x 6), 0, 6)
```

or

```
$s . ("-" x (6-length($s)))
```

Answer (score 3):

`sprintf` only supports padding with `0` and , so no. You can pad with one of those then replace the padding, but the problem with that, is that you run the risk of replacing any padding characters in the original string. For example `sprintf('%-6s', '  M') =~ s/ /-/gr` produces `--M---`.

From the [FAQ](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-pad-a-string-with-blanks-or-pad-a-number-with-zeroes%3F):

> If you need to pad with a character other than blank or zero you can
>   use one of the following methods. They all generate a pad string with
>   the `x` operator and combine that with `$text`. These methods do not
>   truncate `$text`.
>
> Left and right padding with any character, creating a new string:
>
> ```
> my $padded = $pad_char x ( $pad_len - length( $text ) ) . $text;
> my $padded = $text . $pad_char x ( $pad_len - length( $text ) );
> ```
>
> Left and right padding with any character, modifying `$text` directly:
>
> ```
> substr( $text, 0, 0 ) = $pad_char x ( $pad_len - length( $text ) );
> $text .= $pad_char x ( $pad_len - length( $text ) );
> ```

If you do it often, you could wrap it in a subroutine.

```
sub pad {
    my ($str, $padding, $length) = @_;

    my $pad_length = $length - length $str;
    $pad_length = 0 if $pad_length < 0;
    $padding x= $pad_length;
    $str.$padding;
}

say pad('M',       '-', 6);
say pad('MMMMMM',  '-', 6);
say pad('12345',   '-', 6);
say pad('1234567', '-', 6);
say pad('    ',    '-', 6);
```

Output:

```
M-----
MMMMMM
12345-
1234567
    --
```

Comment: Bonus points for introducing me to the 'x' operator. In 10 years of working with perl, I had never seen that and now I feel like a newb.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me the `sprintf('%-6s', '  M') =~ s/ /-/gr` idiom, that opens up some intriguing uses. I didn't expect `sprintf` to be a valid left hand side of an assignment. And thank you Perl :)